# Cron jobs no longer working after upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cron

I had many cron jobs working perfectly before upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. After the upgrade I can run all the defined jobs (using crontab -e) either in terminal or by clicking "Run Selected Task" in GUI "Configure Scheduled Tasks" but all these jobs are not being executed at scheduled (or any other) times... To say once again, I can perfectly without any problem execute all the defined jobs (call to R scripts) using terminal or mentioned GUI.

Output of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep cron` :

```
Jul 25 16:16:41 usernameVB crontab[10530]: (username) LIST (username)
Jul 25 16:16:50 usernameVB crontab[10535]: (username) LIST (username)
Jul 25 16:16:59 usernameVB crontab[10545]: (username) LIST (username)
Jul 25 16:17:01 usernameVB CRON[10549]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 25 16:17:08 usernameVB crontab[10553]: (username) LIST (username)
... (more of the LIST lines)
```

How to make cron jobs run at defined times?

EDIT: Added output of sudo systemctl status cron.service:

```
$sudo systemctl status cron.service
[sudo] password for username: 
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-07-23 02:42:23 EDT; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 734 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─734 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Jul 24 10:17:01 usernameVB CRON[30421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opene
Jul 24 10:17:01 usernameVB CRON[30422]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --re
Jul 24 10:17:01 usernameVB CRON[30421]: pam_unix(cron:session): session close
Jul 25 02:17:01 usernameVB CRON[17013]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opene
Jul 25 02:17:01 usernameVB CRON[17013]: pam_unix(cron:session): session close
Jul 25 13:17:01 usernameVB CRON[3767]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened
Jul 25 13:17:01 usernameVB CRON[3768]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --rep
Jul 25 13:17:01 usernameVB CRON[3767]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed
Jul 25 16:17:01 usernameVB CRON[10548]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opene
Jul 25 16:17:01 usernameVB CRON[10548]: pam_unix(cron:session): session close
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

EDIT 2:
I created jobs using command `$crontab -e` which opens `/tmp/crontab.Rnzw6Y/crontab`. The contents looks like this (several of those jut calling R scripts at different times/days).

```
45 15 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/R --vanilla --quiet < /home/username/code/scripts/R_script_1.R 2>&1 | tee -a "/home/username/log/R_script_1.R - `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d\ \%H:\%M:\%S`.log.txt" # JOB_ID_26
```

Let me point out that running this in terminal works just fine:

```
/usr/bin/R --vanilla --quiet < /home/username/code/scripts/R_script_1.R 2>&1 | tee -a "/home/username/log/R_script_1.R - `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d\ \%H:\%M:\%S`.log.txt"
```

All this worked perfectly fine until upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.

Comment: Please add the output of "sudo systemctl status cron.service" to your question, it might tell us something.

Comment: @BernardWei Added output of "sudo systemctl status cron.service"

Comment: Looks like it is running. Where do you put your cron job configuration? Normally under /etc/cron.hourly, /etc/cron.daily, etc. are place where you put the tasks that need to be run at those interval. If you want other scheduling, create a cron schedule where you can configure precise time and interval. If you need help in setting up that, I can put an answer to your question on exactly how that can be done.

Comment: @BernardWei I have added more info.

Comment: The line is missing the user name, I'll put it in an anwer so I can format it properly.

Comment: Never mind, missed that you are using crontab -e

Comment: Do you see any lines with `RELOAD` in the `cron` related syslog? Did you try something like `* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/testfile` for a generic test? If not, what are the results of that? Also watch the syslog in a second terminal with `journalctl -u cron -f` during this generic test and let us know the outcome.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I see a RELOAD: Jul 28 08:54:01 usernameVB cron[671]: (username) RELOAD (crontabs/username) after I added * * * * * /usr/bin/touch /tmp/testfile using crontab -e. After adding this line the result of $ journalctl -u cron -f is that I see Jul 28 08:55:01 usernameVB CRON[14360]: (username) CMD (/usr/bin/touch /tmp/testfile) . Is there a problem with the rights who can execute /usr/bin/R maybe?
.

Comment: Strange. I have added a simple R script that just prints out "hello" every minute and it seems to work...

Comment: You should add all that information and findings into the question, which makes it easier for others to read up.

Comment: What happens if you just use `* * * * *` for the cronjob you actually want to run. Is it listed in the syslog? Put the command into a shell script and call the shell script in cron which makes it easier to redirect errors. E.g `/usr/local/bin/myr.sh &> /tmp/myr.sh.log` and read the log output.

Comment: @Samo Take a look at `journalctl -u cron` to see all the logs of the cron daemon. More generally, check out `journalctl -e` with latest logs for the whole system and see if you can spot something... Do you have any overrides for `SHELL=...` in either `crontab -l` output or the system-wide `/etc/crontab`? My next suggestion is for you to try to break this down into smaller parts and see if you can isolate the problem. Perhaps try using `date` by itself, since the `%` character is typically special in cron... Good luck debugging this!

Answer (score 1):

First, I ran the command on Ubuntu.

```
crontab -e
```

In the second step I did this:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```